# Not printing the duplicates if one (or more) value is zero

Tags: bash, awk

My input file content is:

```
Header1    Header2
a    2
a    7
b    2
b    5
c    4
c    0
c    5
```

Now, I want to remove duplicates in column A only if any duplicates have value of zero (in column B). So, for the above example, Output should be:

```
Header1    Header2
a    2
a    7
b    2
b    5
```

I have used awk to find 0 in second column:

```
 awk '$2 != 0' file
```

but it prints

```
Header1    Header2
a    2
a    7
b    2
b    5
c    4
c    5
```

How can I omit printing the duplicates if one (or more) of the values is zero? Thanks!

Comment: If there was a line like `x 0` - should that be removed because it has a `0` in $2 or should it not be removed because it doesn't have any duplicates in $1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR == NR{ if($2 == 0) skip[$1]; next } !($1 in skip)' file file
```

```
Header1    Header2
a    2
a    7
b    2
b    5
```

Comment: Nice shot sir :)

Comment: Hey, parsing 2 times the file, first time I see this, thought of an error at a first glance :)

Comment: @anubhava Could you please have a look at `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62292634/generate-where-clause-in-bash-using-variables`