# How can I get the first extension of a filename in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, cut

Is there an inline command which can be used to get the first extension of a file ?

I use the following command to get the latest:

```
FILE="filename.tar.bz2"
EXT="${FILE##*.}"
echo "EXT = ${EXT}"
```

which returns

```
EXT = bz2
```

Is there a similar command to isolate "tar" only ?

Comment: What is `basename` doing in your code?

Comment: @KamilCuk you are right, that's part can be removed (edited)

Answer (score 6):

```
var="config/filename.tar.bz2"
ext=$(basename "$var")    # extract filename only
ext=${ext#*.}             # remove everything in front the first dot
ext=${ext%%.*}            # remove everything after a dot
echo "$ext"
```

Note: uppercase variables by convention are used for exported variables like `COLUMNS`, `LINES` `UID` `PWD` `TERM` etc. Prefer using lowercase variables in your scripts.

Comment: Can you please have a look at this question `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62292634/generate-where-clause-in-bash-using-variables`

Comment: So I did take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62292634/generate-where-clause-in-bash-using-variables), aaaand? (Are you somehow trying to "promote" your question? Please don't do that..)

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on good answer from [@KamilCuk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62292926/7939871), using only POSIX shell grammar and no external command sub-shell call:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

filepath="/path/to/config/filename.tar.bz2.bak"
echo 'filepath:' "$filepath"

# remove everything upto and including last /
filename="${filepath##*/}"
echo 'filename:' "$filename"

# remove everything until and including first dot
all_extensions="${filename#*.}"
echo 'all_extensions:' "$all_extensions"

# remove everything from and including first dot
first_extension="${all_extensions%%.*}"

echo 'First extension:' "$first_extension"

last_extension="${all_extensions##*.}"
echo 'Last extension:' "$last_extension"

# Fill argument array with extensions
IFS='.'; set -- $all_extensions

if [ $# -gt 0 ]
then
  ext_num=1
  printf '\nIterating all %d extensions:\n' $#
  printf '%s\t%s\n' 'ext#' 'extension'
  for extension
  do
    printf '%4d\t%s\n' "$ext_num" "$extension"
    ext_num="$((ext_num+1))"
  done
fi
```

Output:

```
filepath: /path/to/config/filename.tar.bz2.bak
filename: filename.tar.bz2.bak
all_extensions: tar.bz2.bak
First extension: tar
Last extension: bak

Iterating all 3 extensions:
ext#    extension
   1    tar
   2    bz2
   3    bak
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ filename="filename.tar.bz2"
$ echo ${filename##*.}
ext
$ file_ext=${filename##*.} #put to variable
$ echo ${file_ext}
ext
```

Comment: It returns `bz2` as I did, but not `tar` as expected

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "filename.tar.gz" | awk -F "." '{print $2}'
```

This outputs the first instance of a string between periods. In this case, 'tar'.